# value org.json.jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, mysql, json, google-maps

I try to add the markers from my database but i have an error value org.json.jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray

```
05-12 22:30:18.300 2926-2926/com.example.getgpslocation W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"markers":[{"lat":"-0.6092131","lng":"35.2236078"},{"lat":"-0.6340827","lng":"35.1907590"},{"lat":"-0.6292730","lng":"35.1914282"},{"lat":"-0.6292730","lng":"35.2102234"},{"lat":"-0.6139107 ","lng":"35.2128532"},{"lat":"-0.6239696","lng":"35.2201147"},{"lat":"-0.6230255","lng":"35.2174852"},{"lat":"-0.6296344","lng":"35.2231999"},{"lat":"-0.6305786","lng":"35.2246723"},{"lat":"-0.6423803","lng":"35.2206756"},{"lat":"-0.6330677","lng":"35.2163282"},{"lat":"-0.6243836","lng":"35.2161752"},{"lat":"-0.6272590","lng":"35.2102847"},{"lat":"-0.6254565","lng":"35.2031314"},{"lat":"-0.6191050","lng":"35.2011677"},{"lat":"-0.6125390","lng":"35.1946448"},{"lat":"-0.6149852","lng":"35.1927510"},{"lat":"-0.6187617","lng":"35.1926107"},{"lat":"-0.6330677","lng":"35.2163282"},{"lat":"-0.6243836","lng":"35.2161752"},{"lat":"-0.6272590","lng":"35.2102847"},{"lat":"-0.6254565","lng":"35.2031314"},{"lat":"-0.6191050","lng":"35.2011677"},{"lat":"-0.6125390","lng":"35.1946448"},{"lat":"-0.6149852","lng":"35.1927510"},{"lat":"-0.6187617","lng":"35.1926107"},{"lat":"-0.6422793","lng":"35.1904012"},{"lat":"-0.6495749","lng":"35.1859469"},{"lat":"-0.6600892","lng":"35.1788616"},{"lat":"-0.6449401","lng":"35.1798438"},{"lat":"-0.6352412","lng":"35.1802647"},{"lat":"-0.6267440","lng":"35.1816327"},{"lat":"-0.6394620","lng":"35.2172748 "}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

this is my code :

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_Marker,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                jresponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                latitude = Double.parseDouble(jresponse.getString("lat"));
                                longitude = Double.parseDouble(jresponse.getString("lng"));


                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tram_48))
                                        .draggable(true));

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //pDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna try this:

```
try{
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("markers");
```

Because as far as I can see, this should work.

Comment: JSON problem is solved but the markers are not displayed on the map!

Comment: That's a whole different problem. Try debugging it on your own to see why they're not showing, and please consider accepting the answer if it fixed your problem. If you are unable to figure out why they won't show, post a new question here on SO. Cheers bro! :)